# Trouble setting environment variables for CTest tests

Tags: python, cmake, swig, ctest

I'm tasked with building python bindings for a c++-based project (using swig). The project uses cmake to build and ctest to test and the build and test of the bindings are supposed to be integrated into this.

I've gotten the build to work and the tests work when run manually, but I have to set a couple of environment variables in order for them to work and I'm having trouble setting those for the automated process.

I need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH. PYTHONPATH I can get around by manipulating sys.path within the testing script, but that's harder to do with LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So far I have the following added to the CMakelists.txt in the testing directory:

```
#Python wrapper testing

find_package(PythonInterp 3.5 REQUIRED)

if (NOT PYTHONINTERP_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Python interpreter NOT found")
else(NOT PYTHONINTERP_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "Python interpreter found")
  ADD_TEST(NAME testPyMyproj
       COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_scripts/test_pyMyproj.py
       )
  set_property(TEST testPyMyproj PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/)
endif (NOT PYTHONINTERP_FOUND)
```

The error I am getting is

```
ImportError: libMyproj.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which is the library my bindings are linked to and is in the directory specified by `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib/`.

I take this to mean that `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set correctly, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Is there a way to check within the test what the state of the variable is? Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for that. As I suspected the variable is empty.

Comment: Well it didn't solve the main problem of what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do.  `I need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHONPATH. PYTHONPATH I can get around that by...` Can't you just set the envvars?

Comment: I can set them manually and it works then, but this needs to run automatically in a docker container. I am trying to set them in a way that doesn't depend on the pre-existing state of the system.

Comment: Why not use `os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "foo"`?

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work either. I didn't pursue it as that variable is not used directly inside the python environment and I was unsure of its scope.

Comment: Environmental variables affect the global scope outside of Python (the host machine's OS).  But this will likely not affect other programs unless other programs read from the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

Answer (score 22):

You can set environment variables as part of invoking the test by using the `cmake -E env` command. You can modify the `add_test()` call to something like the following:

```
ADD_TEST(NAME testPyMyproj
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib:$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
        ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_scripts/test_pyMyproj.py
)
```

The above assumes a Unix-based host environment, but you could generalise this to support all platforms/generator types with a bit of work if you needed to.

Another alternative is to use the [`ENVIRONMENT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_test/ENVIRONMENT.html) test property which should achieve essentially the same thing:

```
set_tests_properties(testPyMyproj PROPERTIES
    ENVIRONMENT LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib:$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH})
```

Comment: Note that for using the `ENVIRONMENT` property with multiple variables you have to give them as a single semicolon-separated string.

Comment: See also: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html `set_property(TEST [<test1> ...] APPEND PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT [value1 ...])`

Comment: Use something like `\\$<SEMICOLON>` if you need a semicolon in a variable value (for, eg. the `PATH` on Windows)

Comment: An example with multiple values:  set_property(TEST unit_test PROPERTY ENVIRONMENT LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"\\$<SEMICOLON>opt/poky/1.4.2/sysroots/core2-poky-linux/lib)

Answer (score 8):

Craig Scott already provided a great solution via ENVIRONMENT test properties. I just want to add how this works on Windows with the Visual Studio generator and generator expressions:

```
set_tests_properties(
    name_of_test_one
    name_of_test_two
PROPERTIES
    # Make sure DLL is found by adding its directory to PATH
    ENVIRONMENT "PATH=$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:library_target_name>\;$ENV{PATH}"
)
```

Note 1: Instead of a colon, use an escaped semi-colon
Note 2: I'm using the more flexible $ generator expression